# Add image name(text) on image which i am getting from camera or gallery?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-image, android-gallery

I want to add  image name (text) on image which I am getting from camera or gallery?, I have tried  some solution like by Canvas or Using XML file, but I want more feasible solution

Comment: Richa makes it simple - you want to permeant text on the image or just want to show the only layout?

Comment: I want permanent text on the image,Every time user click  photo from camera i want   to Display text on photo also,Ex.Like in Redmi phone camera

Comment: check it -https://inducesmile.com/android/text-on-photo-android-application-example/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the one of best watermark library which help you do your task

https://github.com/huangyz0918/AndroidWM

They also provide different mechanisam to add watermark on your image.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Simply take relative layout in XML and add Textview and ImageView .
```

Now get the Image name from below code 
you can use the substring method to get the name of the file from the path string.

```
String path=":/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/1414240995236.jpg"; 
// it contains your image path...I'm using a temp string...
String filename=path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Comment: i dont want to add in path, i want text over image

Comment: okay , use this library will be more efficient https://github.com/huangyz0918/AndroidWM